# Prove that when d(x,a) and d(y,a) is equal for all $a \in A$ and A countable, dense then x = y

Tags: general-topology

Let A be a dense countable subset of metric space $(X,d)$ and $x, y \in X$. Then the following is true:
$$
\left( \forall_{a \in A} \text{  } d(x,a) = d(y,a) \text{ } \right) \implies x = y
$$
How can I prove this?

Comment: Pick $a_n \to x$.

Comment: If a straight proof doesn't reveal itself automatically, contradiction might be one way to get going. Or in this case, just contraposition.

Comment: @TheoBendit - since A is dense, I am able to pick $a_n \rightarrow x$. Then for arbitrary $\epsilon$ there exists such N that for every $n_0$ > N we have $d(a_{n_0}, x) < \epsilon$. But $d(a_{n_0}, x) = d(a_{n_0}, y)$ and that makes y a limit of $a_n$ too. And since limits are unambiguous and $a_n$ converges, we have x = y. Is that a correct reasoning?

Comment: That looks good to me. Assuming "limits are unambiguous" is something you have already proven.

Comment: @math_beginner Everyone else has weighed in, but yes, that's the proof I was hinting at. Well done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence in $A$ converging to $x$. Then $$0 = d(x,x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} d(x, a_n) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} d(y,a_n) = d(y,x).$$

So $x=y$. The second equality is the continuity of $d$, and the second is your assumption. I don't see why you need countability here though; just $A$ being dense is enough.